# 21m old very smart, seems ready but being super difficult

Tags: toddler, potty-training

My daughter is 21 months old, she’s very bright, she can definitely follow simple directions and she seems ready. She knows pee is supposed to go in her toilet but she won’t pee in it. She’ll pee on the floor around the house by accident and will start to freak out because she doesn’t like to get wet but when I have her sit on the toilet she won’t pee. She’ll hold it in until she can’t anymore and then the cycle repeats itself. Right now we’re trying the naked waist down method and it’s not working at all, it’s actually causing her a lot of stress because she’s crying over every tiny thing.
What should I do??

Answer (score 2):

Give her some time. It sounds Mike she is scared to pee in a potty. That is a normal reaction.

You can read books with her on the potty. Make it a good time.

You can read books with her where other kids sit on a potty.

Comment: Remember that no child ever learns something on the first try - just like how learning to eat can be messy, so can learning to use the toilet.

Answer (score 0):

Try sitting her on the potty and chatting or reading or whatever until she urinates on her own.  Then take a break, and do it again a few hours later.  Sounds like once her body gets used to being relaxed on the potty, and used to the sensation of going there, she'll stick with it.